# Google Apps Script timing out when accessing sheet, but accomplishes tasks

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script running that takes data from about 5 different spreadsheets and adds them to one centralized spreadsheet. The script gives a timeout error for accessing the centralized sheet after the approximate 5-6 minutes it takes for GAS to time itself out. The weird thing is; although it gives a timeout error when adding certain values to certain tabs, it still completes the task consistently. This is the error message:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id ##########.

with # signifying the ID of the centralized spreadsheet.

Comment: Hard to tell with just that information... Reading internet shows a couple of reasons and solutions but it may also be just random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before with different sheets and for 3 different reasons:

**The first one:**

I had reached the actual [limit for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603), so this made the sheet super slow and took some time to load, so I guess that when the script was run, it was not able to access the sheet information; creating the error message.

I tried to fix this by creating a new copy, and it did work for a little while. However, after a few days, it started to happen once more. To fully solved the issue, I had to split the data into 2 new sheets.

**The second one:**

The sheet didn't have as many cells as the other one, but it did a large amount of import ranges formulas, it took a while for the sheet to load when I opened it manually, and I got the same error with the script.

Making a copy of this issue actually worked for me this time, you can also try adding a [Utilities.sleep(300000);](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)) after calling the URL of the Google Sheet to allow it to load and get the data, and after that reads the rest of the code.

**The last one:**

It was an actual bug and got fixed after a while. I found issue trackers about this.

[Issue tracker 1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243563677)

[Issue tracker 2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156958763)

[Issue tracker 3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156530211)

You can report the issue [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#bugs).

Comment: [@David-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14961019/david), If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Since we have to guess because you did not supply a script for us to evaluate I would guess that you are using a range like this sheet.getRange("A1:Z") which  works fine in formulas but in google apps script that places a bunch of nulls between the last row in the sheet all the way to maxrows.  So to correct this always use of these forms `sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),26)` or `sheet.getRange("A1:Z" + sheet.getLastRow())`;  Of course this is just a guess.  If you wish a better answer the please add more details to your question.